# C# Rearranging multi-display positions in Windows

Tags: c#, graphics

Is there a convenient way to rearrange how multiple displays are positioned via C#?

I'm working on a display wall and every time someone unplugs the displays from the computers that are driving them, I have to spend time in the Screen Resolution tool dragging them around. I can automate this process if I can find a way to change the display positions from code.

Comment: I can think of no easy way to slap the person who does that... via C# that is.

Comment: @AustinSalonen that was my first impulse. Unfortunately, he has a legitimate reason. We're still playing with different HW configs, running different machines in parallel, etc. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like using the win32 API is the way to go.

[`ChangeDisplaySettingsEx`](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/ChangeDisplaySettingsEx.html) with friends seems to be the way to go.